# Execute commands in a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am using the 2003 textbook - [http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Shell-Programming-3rd-Edition/dp/0672324903](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324903)

My OS is linux L-ubuntu 13 which is not based on POSIX (I think)

It says that I can store `who | wc -l` in a file called nu and then execute nu. But, before that I need to make this file executable by using `chmod +x file(s)`. This does not work. How do I make the nu "command" work ? I know I can do it by naming nu as nu.sh and then doing `bash nu.sh`, but I want to try this way also.

Comment: `chmod +x nu`, and then run with `./nu`. The `./` before the filename is important

Comment: @user000001 - yes, that works. Since my book does not mention this, can I say that the book is wrong ?

Comment: @user000001 - jgb says that "You should not include . in your PATH." Can you comment on that ? thanks.

Comment: You should not include the `.` in your path, because it will lead it security issues. For example if somehow a file that is named `cp`, that contains `rm *` in it, gets in your directory, next time you try to copy something, you will delete everything. If the `.` is not in your path, there is no such risk

Comment: @user000001 - can you show me the file contents and the command to make this happen ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a file that is not in the PATH, you must give a properly qualified directory name. While giving the name of the file in the current directory is sufficient as an argument to a program, in order to execute a shell script or other executable file, you must give at least a relative path. For example, if the file is in your home directory, which is also the working directory, any of the following are acceptable:

```
./nu
~/nu
/home/username/nu
```

However, simply `nu` will only attempt to search the PATH, which probably includes places such as /bin, /usr/bin, and so on.

Comment: I dont know how all these path or directory things work in unix. I don't know why only ./nu works for me.

Comment: Since my book does not mention this, can I say that the book is wrong ?